# php slim detect client abort (HTTP)

Tags: php, http, slim

In slim framework V3 how can I detect if the client closed the connection ?

I have tried:
ignore_user_abort(false);
and tried checking connection_status() and  connection_aborted() in a loop with no luck.

php 5.6.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems one need to output something from php and then call ob_flush() because php only handles errors from the browser. Here's a way to do it without outputing anything, which will work fine for long-polling scenarios:

```
/* returns ESTABLISHED, CLOSE_WAIT, LAST_ACK, etc */
function getConnectionStatus() {

    $remote_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?:($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']?:$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']);
    $remote_port=$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];

    $cmd="netstat -tn | fgrep ' $remote_ip:$remote_port '";

    $pfp=popen($cmd,"r");
    $buf = fgets($pfp, 1024);
    pclose($pfp);

    $buf=preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $buf); //remove multiple spaces
    $buf=trim($buf);

    $buf_r=explode(" ",$buf);

    if (count($buf_r)) {
        $state=$buf_r[count($buf_r)-1];
        return trim($state);
    }

    return "NOTFOUND";
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
while(...) {
/* ... longpolling check code here ...*/

    if  (getConnectionStatus() != "ESTABLISHED") {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends not from Slim but from PHP in general. PHP close connection just after execution script.

If you want create persistance connection you need to look to long polling connection.

http://phptrends.com/dig_in/php-long-polling

Comment: I'm not asking that, I'm asking how to detect HTTP client disconnection inside the PHP script.

Comment: The long-polling scripts I found in the provided link don't handle client disconnection, and will continue to loop forever or until a web-server timeout, thus using  high resources.